# Return HTML code inside PHP function return

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am very new to PHP and I was handed over a project that has some existing PHP code.
I was asked to add hyperlink to the email address, so I want to know how to add HTML code in the function return.

```
public function mail()
{
  return (new Mail)
    ->subject('Welcome')
    ->message('Send questions to', <a href="mailto:xxx@email.com">xxx@email.com</a>);
}
```

Let's assume that everything in the Mail class works. Both of the subject and message methods return the strings inside the brackets.
Can anyone tell me if this code works? I can't run the program for some reason

Comment: Mail is a class that generates a new page that outputs these return message and have the function to send an email

Comment: yes it's custom written code

Comment: Then people won't be able to help you as no one knows what the method `message` inside the class `Mail` actually does

Comment: the method simply returns a string

Comment: That's invalid PHP (HTML inside PHP). Move your link inside the string and remove the `,`

Comment: so just  `->message('Send questions to <a href="mailto:xxx@email.com">xxx@email.com</a>');`

Answer (score -1):

Usually we write like this

```
public function returnHtml {
     echo "//and here we write html code"
     //for example
     echo "<h1> hi<h1>" 
}
```

also you can try something like this

```
function TestBlockHTML ($replStr) {
return <<<HTML
    <html>
    <body><h1>{$replStr}</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: This won't help OP at all. OP is trying to add `HTML` to the content of an e-mail